# How to pass a whole crate to a procedural macro?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to pass my whole crate to a procedural macro.

I've tried putting this code on top of my `lib.rs`:

```
#![my_macro]
#![feature(proc_macro)]
extern crate my_macro;
use my_macro::{my_macro};
```

and failed: `error: cannot find attribute macro 'my_macro' in this scope`

I've tried also putting the macro invocation below the `use` clause:

```
#![feature(proc_macro)]
extern crate my_macro;
use mock_macro::{my_macro};
#![my_macro]
```

but failed as well: `error: an inner attribute is not permitted in this context`

Is it possible to do it? (I know `syn` has a function for parsing a whole crate)

Comment: Not possible yet: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41430

Comment: Thank you. If you make it an official answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible as of Rust 1.25.0-nightly as long as you enable `feature(extern_absolute_paths)` and use an absolute path for your attribute macro.

```
#![::my_crate::my_macro]
#![feature(extern_absolute_paths, proc_macro)]
```

The issue of attribute macros invoked at the crate root is being tracked in [rust-lang/rust#41430](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41430). We expect to remove the limitation that the attribute must be specified with an absolute path as the implementation of [RFC 2126](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44660) proceeds further. You may run into other limitations too, in particular attempting to inject functions into the crate from a crate-level procedural macro currently [crashes the compiler](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/45458).